# How to get current module object from model in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have module `ticket`.

Module class has propery `UserClassName` (string).

In this module I have model called `Dialog`.

Within this model, I want to get access to the module property `UserClassName`.

How I can get module object from my model `Dialog`?

P.S. From controllers I can do next: `$this->module`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use `className()` to obtain the class name.

```
$yourModule = yourPath\YourModule::className();
```

Or for getting the module id you can use:

```
Yii::$app->controller->module->id;
```

Answer (score 4):

we can identify the module,controller and action method as follows in yii2
`Yii::$app->controller->module->id;`(For Getting Module ID) 
`Yii::$app->controller->id;`(For Getting Controller ID)
`Yii::$app->controller->action->id;`(For Getting Controller action ID)

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution (I need same for me too). To get module object - very simple:

```
\Yii::$app->getModule('moduleName')->propertyOrMethod;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$module = MyModuleClass::getInstance();
```

The getInstance() method will return the currently requested instance of the module class. If the module is not requested, the method will return null. Note that you do not want to manually create a new instance of the module class because it will be different from the one created by Yii in response to a request.